# Converting JarEntry to String

Tags: java, string, jar

I iterate some JarEntries that I know are text files. But how do I convert the JarEntry into a string when I find it?

```
    JarEntry jarEntry = connection.getJarEntry();
    JarFile archive = connection.getJarFile();
    Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = archive.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        String name = jarEntry.getName();
        if (entry.getName().startsWith(name) && !entry.isDirectory()) {
                     // Convert this entry to a string
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

I think this should do it:

```
            InputStream inputStream = archive.getInputStream(entry);
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, "UTF-8");
            String theString = writer.toString();
            System.out.println(theString);
```

Comment: name is already the string, or doy you want the content of the text file tpo be read in as string?

Comment: Yes its the content of the entry that must be converted into a string

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

```
private String readFileFromJar(String pathname) throws IOException {

InputStream configStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(pathname);
try {
    FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
    /* Instead of using default, pass in a decoder. */
    return Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
}
finally {
    stream.close();
 }
```

}

Then:

```
if (entry.getName().startsWith(name) && !entry.isDirectory()) {
        String content = readFile(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have found your entry do this

```
        BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(archive.getInputStream(jarEntry)));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int c = 0; (c = rdr.read()) != -1;) {
            sb.append((char) c);
        }
        String txt = sb.toString();
```